# When the all cells are editable, unable to select row

Tags: tabulator

Neither select-row work nor row-click works when the cell are editable. Anyway to get row selected?

If I click inbetween the cells then it works but it's not practicle click small space inbetween cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to show an example of what you are trying to do. A JSFiddle would be helpful. Still if I'm following correctly what you want to add to your table layout is:

http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/format#format-builtin

"Row Handle

The handle formatter fills the cell with hamburger bars, to be used as a row handle

{title:"Example", field:"example", formatter:"handle"}"